# Titanium; recommended approach to "include" going forward?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, pubnub

The Titanium code examples located [here](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/master/titanium) suggest that you include the pubnub.js file using **Ti.include('pubnub.js');**

Yet, the Titanium 3.x documentation indicates that "include" is depreciated since version 3.3.0 of Titanium, see [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium-method-include).

Question:
What can be done to use the titanium-recommended approach of using "require()" instead of "include()"?  Or, will the pubnub example code be updated at some point?

Answer (score 0):

`pubnub.js` is a self executed function
as you see if you open the js file

```
(function(){})();
```

so what you can do to use require it convert the self executed function to normal function e.g.

```
function pubnub(){};
```

this export your module like this

```
module.exports=pubnub;
```

and then when you want to use file library you can simply doit by using require

```
var p=require("/pubnub")
var pubnub=new p();
```

Answer (score 0):

the pubNub sample code needs to be updated... there is no need to use Ti.include.

If you look in the code, you will see that the example is actually using `require` when working with the library

```
// ----------------------------------
// INIT PUBNUB
// ----------------------------------
var pubnub = require('pubnub')({
    publish_key   : 'demo',
    subscribe_key : 'demo',
    ssl           : false,
    origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com'
});
```